# Can 'superiore' mean 'previous years' (plural)?

Tags: vocabulary, latin-to-english-translation, new-latin

Under the year 1558, George Buchanan writes (*Rerum Scoticarum Historia*, 1582):

*Hoc anno et superiore etiam, caussa religionis quodam modo iacuisse videbatur, quod morte...*

In the standard English translation (James Aikman, 1827), this is translated:

*The cause of religion, during this and the former year, appeared rather to stand still; for the one party, somewhat checked by the death of George Wishart, was satisfied with being allowed quietly to worship God in their native tongue and reason soberly about divinity; the other being deprived of a leader, by the death of the cardinal, showed that they wanted the power, rather than the inclination, to persecute; for his successor thirsted more after the money than the blood of his adversaries, nor almost ever behaved with cruelty, unless when the plunder afforded him the means of enjoying his licentious pleasures.*

Aikman translates *superiore* as 'the former year', but the references to George Wishart and to Cardinal Beaton are to the events of 1546 and the years following. The passage would make better sense if 'the former year' was replaced by 'former years'; but is this a possible translation of *superiore*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, *superiore* is clearly singular, *anno superiore* is a standing expression meaning “the previous year,” and it is unheard of to use the singular *annus* for several years.

Comment: Do you think *superior* always refer to the year before the narrative present, or can its meaning shift depending on context? I came across this passage from Cicero's oration *In Verrem*: "labefactarat enim vehementer aratores iam superior annus, proximus vero funditus everterat." It seems to mean, "The year before last crippled the farmers; last year completely destroyed them."

Comment: Many thanks for this.

Comment: @brianpck I take it for granted that the reference point must be inferred from context and cannot always simply be assumed to be the narrative present. In the example from the Scottish annals, this would appear to be *hoc anno* – whatever year that is.